# Wie sagt man urinieren und defäkieren in der Kindersprache?

Tags: word-usage, regional, baby-talk

Mein 4-jähriger Sohn geht zur Deutschen Schule Rom (die ich selber 15 Jahre lang besucht habe), und daher versuche ich mit ihm soviel wie möglich Deutsch zu sprechen.

Aus meiner Kindheit kenne ich *Pipi machen* und *Pupu machen*, aber *Pupu* scheint von meiner Oma dem Italienischen entlehnt worden zu sein. Das andere Paar, was ich in bayrischen Kinderheimen gelernt habe, ist *klein machen* und *groß machen*.

Die Frage ist:

1. Wie drückt man am besten *urinieren* und *defäkieren* in der Kindersprache aus?
2. Welche regionale Unterschiede gibt es da?

Comment: es gibt verschiedenen Verniedlichungsformen für die Kindesalter, für größere Kinder klingt Kindergartensprache dann albern, Toschos Antwort ist neutral für alle Alter

Comment: defä... was? Das hab ich noch nie gehört...

Comment: @Em1, ich benutze gerne einen geeigneteren Ausdruck, wenn es einen gibt.

Comment: @Em1 Tja, so sagt der Biologe ;-)

Comment: Hier gibts n gutes Video dazu ;) -> http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JwKIc7wkaNo

Comment: @TechRobin: Danke, aber für mich nicht sehr nützlich. Das ist ein Wörter-Potpourri ohne jegliche Information.

Comment: Ich dachte der medizinische Ausdruck für defäkieren wäre "stuhlen".

Comment: @Wernfried: Nein, das ist medizinischer Slang.

Answer (score 19):

My parents often used `Aa machen` for defäkieren respectively `Pipi machen` for urinieren when I was a young child.

Reference: [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aa_(Kindersprache)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aa_%28Kindersprache%29)

Comment: _Aa machen_ ist tatsächlich die einzige Übersetzung für _fare la cacca_ in meinem Deutsch-Italienisch Wörterbuch von Sansoni. Was mich ein wenig verwundert ist, dass ich diesen Ausdruck in mehr als 50 Jahren nie gehört habe. Übrigens, _Aa_ müsste der Aussprache nach eigentlich _A-a_ (oder _A-A_?) geschrieben werden.

Comment: Ist hier (Ostösterreich) weit verbreitet. Als nicht gerade hochsprachlichen Ausdruck habe ich mir über die Verschriftlichung bisher keine Gedanken gemacht :)

Comment: Im fränkischen/oberbayerischen Raum sind diese 2 Ausdrücke ebenfalls absolut geräuchlich und mM nach die angemehmsten Umschreibungen

Comment: Meine Eltern und ich sind Oberbayern! Hier ist das ziemlich geläufig. `aa` is pronounced a-a (two separate As), indeed.

Comment: Anmerkung: im Grimm ist es _der_ Aa, im Duden _das_ Aa

Answer (score 7):

`pullern` für urinieren.

`kacken` für defäkieren.

Comment: Interessante Kindersprache...

Comment: @Em1 Die ganze Varianten `xyz machen` helfen nicht wirklich bei der Sprachbildung der Kinder.

Comment: @Toscho Wir haben als Kinder "AA machen" gesagt. Ich finde dennoch, dass es meiner Sprachbildung nicht wirklich geschadet hat.

Comment: Wenn es stimmt, was Raphael in seiner Antwort sagt, hat _kacken_ eine negative Konnotation, und ist daher nicht für den Umgang mit meinem Sohn geeignet (in meinem Fall würde auch der Anklang zum italienischen _cacare_ dazukommen, was eindeutig eine negative Konnotation hat (im Gegensatz zu _fare la cacca_))

Comment: `kacken` hat keine negative Konnotation, denn es bezieht sich auf genau das, was es ausdrückt. Andere Sachen mit Kot in Verbindung zu bringen, indem man sie als `Scheiß[Sache]` oder `Kack[Sache]` bezeichnet, mag negativ konnotiert sein, aber `Scheißscheiße` ist es wohl sicher nicht.

Comment: Mit dem _denn_ in ersten Satz bin ich nicht einverstanden. Das genügt nicht.

Comment: Was bedeutet _Scheißscheiße_?

Comment: @WalterTross Es hat kein weitere Bedeutung als `Scheiße`.

Comment: Statt `kacken` sagen wir `kackan` (Partizip: `gekackat`), das klingt nicht ganz so hart. `A-a` ist mir zu bescheuert.

Comment: @Toscho: Auch andere absolut nicht salonfähige Wörter haben in der Hinsicht, dass sie sich genau auf das beziehen, was sie ausdrücken, keine negative Konnotation. Das heißt aber dennoch nicht, dass sie bedenkenlos verwendbar wären oder gar in Anwesenheit von Kindern geäußert werden sollten, um die es in der Frage nun mal geht.

Comment: Ich höre oft "Ich muss mal groß" (kacken) und "Ich muss mal klein" (pullern). Auch Verniedlichungen kommen vor, z.B. "ömmeln" für kacken, "lulu / pipi / pinkeln" für pullern.

Answer (score 7):

In der ganzen Liste fehlt eindeutig das *müssen*:

> "Ich muss mal!"
>
> "Gross oder klein?"

Die Bedeutung dürfte eindeutig sein.

Answer (score 6):

Ich bin in der Steiermark geboren und aufgewachsen, da hieß es:

Für »urinieren«:

> ludeln
>   Lulu machen

»Lulu« ist in Österreich übrigens in der Kindersprache sowohl das Wort für Urin als auch für das Ausscheidungsorgan bei Kindern (sowohl Penis als auch Scheide).

Für »scheißen« (gibt es Leute, die tatsächlich im täglichen Leben »defäkieren« sagen???):

> bogerln

In Wien sagt man

> Lulu machen

und

> A a machen
>   gacksen
>   Gacksi machen

Die Verkleinerungsform von »Gacksi« ist das »Gackerl«, und mit diesem Wort wurde in Wien dafür geworben den Hundekot nicht liegen zu lassen, sondern in ein Sackerl zu geben: http://www.wien.gv.at/rk/msg/2007/0920/016.html

Comment: Natürlich wird man im täglichen Sprachgebrauch nicht *defäkieren* verwenden; *scheißen* empfinde ich dann aber als durchaus etwas zu hart. IdR wird man den Sachverhalt eben umschreiben: Ich muss aufs Klo (im Dialekt auch gerne "ich geh' aufs Häusl") oä. Wie gesagt, an derben Ausdrücken für derlei Ausscheidungsvorgänge mangelt es ja nun wirklich nicht, aber es war ja explizit nach Kindersprache gefragt.

Comment: Mein Vater war gebürtiger Oberschlesier und sagte auch "Lulu". Scheint also nicht nur in Österreich verwendet zu werden.  "gacksen" ist vermutlich eine Variante von "kacken".

Answer (score 5):

In my Jewish home we had *pish* and *plop*. The latter I took to be baby-talk on my mother's part, but I always assumed "pisch" would have been a good German word. Apparently not?

As an adult, I always preferred  the expressions "number 1" and "number 2" until I ran into some kind of big misunderstanding with a Lebanese friend. In the end he explained that in Lebanon, it's the other way around. The best way to avoid confusion, he concluded, was to talk about "the big thing" and "the small thing". I think this would work in any language.

Comment: Duden has pischen, although it might be Austrian: http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/pischen

Comment: Thank you Marty - even if it's not an answer to my question. Anyway the proposal of your friend corresponds to the German _groß machen_ and _klein machen_. To your question, _pish_ is an onomatopoeia just like the German _pissen_, and _plop_ is too (probably without a German counterpart).

Comment: Friends of mine use *pischern* when asking their dog whether he wants to urinate. Should also work for children.

Comment: "Pischen" is not that unusual, but it is certainly a variant of "pissen".

Answer (score 4):

Für "urinieren": `pieseln` oder `bieseln`. Ist hier in Süd-Bayern auch unter Erwachsenen in Gebrauch (sehr informell natürlich bzw. unter Freunden). Was Kindersprache angeht, kann ich nur für meinen 2,5-jährigen Sohn sprechen, der es versteht und manchmal auch benutzt. Die Variante mit 'p' steht im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pieseln), mit 'b' scheint es die bairische Schreibweise zu sein (aber da kenne ich mich als Zugereister nicht aus.)

Comment: *Pieseln* kann in Norddeutschland (zumindest in meiner Familie ...) auch das Verb für leichten Regen sein.

Comment: @Raketenolli das ist eher ein Reim auf *nieseln*, die Bedeutung *urinieren* bleibt aber bestehen.

Comment: Wenn wir schon bei der Mundart sind: Die schwäbischen Kinder sagen "I muss a Rolle" - Was beim hochdeutschen Turnlehrer schonmal zu Missverständnissen führen kann.

Answer (score 4):

Ich bilde mir ein, dass die überregional üblichste Bezeichnung in der deutschen Kindersprache "Kacka machen" ist. (Ich selber bin nicht damit aufgewachsen, sondern mit "einen Stinker machen".) Bisher bin ich davon ausgegangen, dass man das "Kaka machen" schreibt, in Analogie zu "Pipi machen". Aber ich beuge mich der Macht des Duden.

Neben dem *Kacka* (Maskulinum oder Neutrum) kennt der Duden auch noch das *Aa* (Aussprache *A-A*). Es scheint mir eine offensichtliche Ableitung von *Kacka* zu sein.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt hier wohl große regionale (und auch familiäre) Unterschiede. Das Wort "harnen" würde ich aktiv übrigens nicht verwenden, wenn man keine Umschreibung möchte (auf die Toilette gehen), dann wäre "urinieren" meine erste Wahl.

Für Erwachsene gibt es natürlich auch jede Menge derberer Ausdrücke. Für Kinder? "Pipi machen" ist in Ordnung, in Österreich (?) verwendet man auch oft "Lulu". "Groß" und "klein" ist in Ordnung, aber keine Kindersprache: so würde zB auch der Arzt mit einem Patient reden. "Pupu" kenne ich im Deutschen nicht, Kinder verwenden bisweilen den Ausdruck "Gacki" oder "Kacki".

Comment: Werde in der Frage _harnen_ mit _urinieren_ ersetzen. Danke

Comment: _Auf die Toilette gehen_ (oder _aufs Klo gehen_) unterscheidet leider nicht zwischen "groß" und "klein"

Comment: True, but what does that matter under normal circumstances? Of course it's sometimes different with children, agreed.

Comment: With small children it makes quite a difference

Answer (score 2):

In Thüringen (Germany) as a small kid they told me *A-a machen* was to defecate, another woman spoke about *käckern,* which does also sound milder instead of the vulgar *kacken. Pipi/Lulu machen* (to urinate) or *pullern/lullern/strullern* is appropriate for smaller children, too. Later, maybe in school or already in later kindergarden times it was *ich muss mal klein* (urinate) and *Ich muss mal groß* (defecate). Adults can say *ich geh mal wohin/ich geh mal um die Ecke.*

I also know the word *pischen*, probably related to the [jewish 'pish'](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11916). There is a tradition which I got to know in our area Thüringen. It is called **Pisch-Bier-Party**. That means people, especially men meet to have some drinks (beer) when one man has become a father and the woman is still in hospital. The explanation is to drink a lot so that the child will be able to "gut pischen/pullern".

Answer (score 2):

Mein Großvater (der im Allgäu geboren wurde und den größten Teil seines Lebens in München verbrachte) sagte für urinieren "Wisi machen" oder "a Wiserl machen". Das habe ich auch von anderen bayrischen Sprechern so gehört.

Answer (score 1):

Mein 3-jähriger Sohn sagt

> Ich muss Pipi machen.

und

> Ich muss Schissi machen.

Wir haben nie versucht, eine spezielle Kleinkindersprache zu pflegen, sodass dies wohl eine Mischung aus dem ist, was wir sagen und was er woanders hört.

Interessant finde ich, dass unabhängig von der genauen Bezeichnung für das was heraus kommt, immer *eine Sache gemacht* wird, statt ein einzelnes Verb dafür benutzt.

PS: Urinieren habe ich ja schon in der Sprache gehört, aber defäkieren noch nie.

Answer (score 1):

Ich war in einem katholischen Kindergarten, da hat man immer von scheißen und pissen gesprochen. Ich denke, das ist heutzutage auch normal.